# subversion status -u to diff

Tags: svn, diff

When i do a `svn status -u` I get a list of files that need updating. I'd like to feed this list to `svn diff` so that I can have a list of changes in one one file I can look over. 
Can I do this? If so I am not sure how to do a foreach on this.

EDIT:
linux bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD .
```

will show you the changes to the files as far as I know.